# How to hardcode json in NSString

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to hardcode json in NSString variable. But I get errors. JSON is this:

```
{
    "sub-categories": {
        "parent": "1",
        "count": "2",
         "sub-category": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Buy"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Sell"
        }]
     }
}
```

I do this but it doesn't work:

```
NSString *jsonArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{
                       'sub-categories\": {
                       \"parent\": \"1\",
                       \"count\": \"2\",
                       \"sub-category\": [{
                       \"id\": \"1\",
                       \"name\": \"Buy\"
                       },
                       {
                       \"id\": \"2\",
                       \"name\": \"Sell\"
                       }]
                       }
                       }"];
```

Comment: So just escape everything that is a objective-c control character, wrap in quotes and place @ at the beginning.

Comment: I do this but it doesn't work:

`NSString *jsonArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{
                           'sub-categories\": {
                           \"parent\": \"1\",
                           \"count\": \"2\",
                           \"sub-category\": [{
                           \"id\": \"1\",
                           \"name\": \"Buy\"
                           },
                           {
                           \"id\": \"2\",
                           \"name\": \"Sell\"
                           }]
                           }
                           }"];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many languages a string literal cannot contain a new line. You can either write the whole JSON in 1 line, or split the string like this:

```
NSString* json = @"{"
                 @"  \"sub-categories\": {"
                 @"    \"parent\": \"1\", "
                 ...
                 @"}";
```